# iis asp.net Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () randomly

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-403, iis-10

my website is hosted on iis 10 
Since my pages change frequently I have inserted this in the headers:

`cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`
`pragma: no-cache`
`expires: 0`

After doing this all my pages have resources that don't load. 
I think the problem was already there, but having the resources in the cache I didn't notice it.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

In the Event Viewer on the server I saw these errors:

```
The description for Event ID 1 from source ModSecurity cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

[client 207.46.13.73] ModSecurity: collection_retrieve_ex: Unable to retrieve collection (name "ip", key "207.46.13.73_4f1ba30e7e0a1348a60fa661e5bb8b958e7f7aa5"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname "VULTR-GUEST"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "12105675809109317484"]
```

and

```
The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to delete the history directory 'C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000214'. The directory will be skipped and ignored. Note that the directory may still get deleted in the future if the service restarts. The data field contains the error number.
```

So I tried to disable ModSecurity, but the problem didn't go away. There are just no more errors in the EventViewer.

The amazing thing is that every time I refresh the page (ctrl + F5) the blocked resources change. Sometimes some images, others some css, others the fonts etc.
They always change, it uploads the images that it did not upload before and it does not upload the images it had uploaded before.

I had checked everything, but I don't understand what is happening. The problem exists in all devices.

The only particular thing is that I use CORS in the web.config 
I don't know if it's relevant.

```
    <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
        <add origin="https://example.com" allowed="true" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120" />
        <add origin="https://*.example.com" allowed="true" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120" />
    </cors>
```

I contacted support, but they also don't know what to do. 
Do you have any ideas? 
Thanks 
Luca

Comment: What happens if you try loading the missing "resources" directly in your browser?

Comment: You need to enable FRT and see more details on those 403 errors first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Can you check the sub status code of 403 in browser? If you remove those cache relative headers, does the issue still exists? Don't forget to use failed request tracing check what happened about 403 error.

Comment: @mxmissile Resources are always opened correctly directly from the browser.

Comment: @Bruce-Zhang Sub status code is 403.502 . If I remove the cache directives from the header the problem persists. I mentioned this because it is the reason why I have only seen the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) status codes in Microsoft Internet Information Services says:

> 403.502 - Forbidden: Too many requests from the same client IP; Dynamic IP Restriction Maximum request rate limit reached.

So I increased it to 50 calls in 200 milliseconds and the site started working again.